# Multiple method calls in the constructor and dependency injection

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php, dependency-injection, constructors

I was asked to refactor some almost ureadable spaghetti code into object-oriented architecture.

I have some doubts regarding a class that I designed. Here is the class' skeleton:

```
require_once 'inc/FeaturedCarousel/Carousel.php';
class FeaturedCarousel
{
    private $currentCategory;
    private $allFeaturedAdvertisers = array();
    private $metaData = array();
    private $featuredAdvertisersIds = array();
    private $dataForDisplay = array();

    public function __construct($currentCategory)
    {
        $this->currentCategory = $currentCategory;
        $this->getAllFeaturedAdvertisers();
        $this->getAllAdvertisersMetaData();
        $this->getFeaturedAdvertisersInCurrentCategory();
        $this->getDataForDisplay();
    }    

    private function getAllFeaturedAdvertisers()
    {
    }

    private function getAllAdvertisersMetaData()
    {
    }

    private function getFeaturedAdvertisersInCurrentCategory()
    {             
    }

    private function getDataForDisplay()
    {     
    }

    public function displayCarousel()
    {
        new FeaturedCarousel\Carousel($this->dataForDisplay);
    }      
}
```

The class is initiated like this:

```
$carousel = new FeaturedCarousel($currentCategory);
$carousel->displayCarousel();
```

The class' role is to prepare data for display, and then display it using an external `Carousel` class that is instantiated in the `displayCarousel()` method.

There may be major aspects of it that should refactored. Please note that I have already implemented all the methods so there is no need to focus on their implementation.

Here are my questions -

1. All methods required to generate data for display are trigerred one by one in the constructor. Each of these methods generates a private property required by the method called next. Therefore, if any of the methods fails, there is really no point in calling subsequent methods. How should I  address those possible method failures?
2. The `displayCarousel()` method instantiates another class that is responsible for the actual rendering of HTML content. At the moment the `Carousel` class is just `required` and instantiated in the method call. Should the `Carousel` class be 'injected' into my class before it is used?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239416/multiple-method-calls-in-the-constructor-and-dependency-injection

Comment: @gnat The other post has now been deleted. I kept it live for a while longer due to very interesting discussion that the the topic started. But as I said - no cross-posting anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if any of the methods fails, there is really no point in calling subsequent methods. How should I address those possible method failures?

Throw an exception.

> Should the Carousel class be 'injected' into my class before it is used?

Yes, if there is more than one implementation of `Carousel` (including the possibility of a mock object for unit testing purposes).  Then you will inject an `ICarousel`.

Comment: you're truly the persion I've been waiting for this whole day across several Stack sites. Much appreciated! :)